# Are there resources for simulating and/or theoretically describing solitons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, solitons

Recently there are striking new ideas emerging on "lower level" dynamics with respect to quantum mechanics involving fluid mechanics principles, including hints of [soliton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton)-like aspects to particle physics dynamics.[1][2][3]

However, while there are now possibly decades of physical/empirical experiments, it does not seem that solitons have been studied much in the literature from a more abstract/theoretical or a 3D computational/simulation point of view.

> Are there papers on 3D mesh/grid simulation experiments on soliton dynamics, in particular some that relate to particle physics?

Additionally, survey papers, if any exist, would also be helpful.

[1] [Pilot wave hydrodynamics](http://math.mit.edu/~bush/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Bush-AnnRev2015.pdf) / Bush

[2] [Why bouncing droplets are a pretty good model of quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4356) / Brady, Anderson

[3] [Have We Been Interpreting Quantum Mechanics Wrong This Whole Time?](http://www.wired.com/2014/06/the-new-quantum-reality/) / Wolchover

Comment: There are anywhere from ~5-10 papers per month in the journal _Physics of Plasmas_ that discuss all sorts of different types of solitons and all of them are modeled.  I did not post this as an answer because it relates to plasma, not particle physics.

Comment: You can also look at an example I made in Mathematica here:  [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63526/19732](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63526/19732).